# How to install the real Firefox on Raspian?

Tags: firefox, debian

Raspian uses Iceweasel instead of Firefox. However, it lacks plugin support and most of my favorites don't work. I've tried [this guide](https://thestandardoutput.com/2013/06/install-the-real-firefox-on-debian-7/) but I'm getting the following error (manually translated):

`Error getting http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/debian/Release expected entry »import/binary-armhf/Packages« couldn't be found`

So what is best way to install the "real" Firefox on Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there's an error is because that repo doesn't support armhf try installing using apt-src.

Comment: Could you please provide me with some more details. I've nerver used apt-src before.

Comment: first add `deb-src http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import` to `/etc/apt/source.list` then run `apt-get install apt-src` then to compile firefox from source run `apt-src build firefox` which should download the source and compile it. For more info go to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/apt-src.1p.html

Comment: Thank you! If anyone else tries to do this, you need to run `apt-src install firefox` before `apt-src build firefox` to resolve dependencies.